# Check the value of the field in HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field which should take input in format HH:MM (it can be `00:01`, `01:19`, `25:00`, `99:34`, `123:12`)

So before submitting the form I need to check whether the value is in any of the above formats else throw an error message .

The field:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="totalDuration" id="total_duration" class="" />
```

Validation code goes here

```
function validate(){
    var totalDuration = $("#total_duration").val();

    // Rest of the code which checks value is in given format
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do;

```
function validate(){
  var totalDuration = $("#total_duration").val();

  return /^\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(totalDuration);
}
```

this is a regular expression which checks for 2 digits followed by a ":" followed by 2 more digits. It could be more precise (i.e. checking for <24 hours and <60 minutes)

If you want to check for *at least* 2 hour digits (to accept 123:12 per your example), try the regular expression `/^\d{2,}:\d{2}$/`

To check for two *or* three hour digits, do; `/^\d{2,3}:\d{2}$/`

Comment: How can you make it more precise in an elegant way?

Comment: In my case , it can be theree digits before :  like 123:47

Comment: @Lipis: I'm not too sure of an *elegant* solution; perhaps someone more confident with regular expressions can chip in with that :).

Comment: @Hussy: check out the 2nd part of my answer. If the max number of hours is 3 digits, add a `3` after the `,`; `/\d{2,3}:\d{2}/`

Comment: @Matt you probably want to anchor your regex with `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, or else "pink poodle 12:00 submarine" will match.

Comment: @Pointy: Oops, thanks ;). Stupid me for not using `pink poodle 12:00 submarine` as one of my quick tests... :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs **00:00 - 23:59** range:

```
function validate(){
  var totalDuration = $("#total_duration").val();

  return /^([2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$/.test(totalDuration);
}
```

Range **01:00 - 12:59**:

```
function validate(){
  var totalDuration = $("#total_duration").val();

  return /^([1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9])|([0][1-9]:[0-5][0-9])$/.test(totalDuration);
}
```